# write entire object to log in java

Tags: java, android, logging, cordova-plugins

I often find myself in situations where I want to do something like javascript where I can say:

```
console.log(object)
```

and this will just print the entire object, and all functions names in the object. In php I used this nice function:

```
function print_object($object) {
    echo '<pre class="notifytiny">' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($object,      true)) . '</pre>';
}
```

that is the single most useful function I ever used in php.

I know that you can debug java, and step through the code, then eventually look at the object in an object viewer, but this is a hassle. I want to just print an object, also I am using Cordova which does not make it easy to debug.

Is there any way to do this in Java without overriding the toString method?

Comment: Is this about `Java` or `Javascript`? If it's Java, then you can have a look at `Logger` for more information.

Comment: sorry for the confusion Java, Javascript is super easy

Comment: You may want to use the debugger to inspect the object. In Java, the `toString()` method is called to produce a string representing the object. You can define it in your class to do what you want. This needs to be done for each class. Alternatively, and it will add a lot of code and potentially fail, is to use some serialization library which uses reflection to find fields. For example, Jackson can do this to produce JSON, but only if your object graph has no reference loops and/or is annotated appropriately.

Comment: well i cant really use the debugger because i am making a cordova plugin. this site has a solution, but it is a pain:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465014/how-to-debug-a-cordova-plugin-for-android

Comment: You should use a Logger, doing something like `logger.info(myObject);`.
In order to obtain a useful string representation of an object, you have to implement the `toString()` method of its class, so that you can see the object contents in your log.
If you can't implement `toString()`, you can use the `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(Object)` method included in **Commons Lang** library.

Comment: I suppose you could use a JSON serializer (or another format) and print the resulting JSON string. That would provide a fairly readable string and it wouldn't require a custom toString() for every class. Perhaps GSON.

Comment: `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(Object)`  this method works pretty well, but i mostly just gives junk variables in the object, if you give it an intent

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("    intent    "+gson.toJson(data));
            tolog(sb.toString());`

this works pretty well, but if the object is too big it will crash android

Answer (score 2):

You can just print the object to stdout using System.out.println(object). You can customize the information that is printed by overriding the toString() method of the class the object belongs, if the class is defined by your code.

You can also try using Log4J, a widely used library to set up logging.

Comment: i could do that, but then i have to set it up what if i want to print an intent, should i override every new class that i want to log

Comment: can Log4J log a class?

Comment: Overriding to String is a common approach, but you have to do that for every class. Instead, you could write a helper method to log all fields using reflection. Maybe there is already some library that does that.

Comment: here is a sample on how to override the toString() for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075360/debugging-the-state-of-my-objects