# Logging / Debugging the state of my objects

Tags: java, android, debugging

Say I have a custom object called Car. All of the fields in it are private.

```
public class Car {

    private String mName;
    private String mBrand;
    private String mModel;

    public Car(String name, String brand, String model) {
        mName = name;
        mBrand = brand;
        mModel = model;
    }

    // more class methods here
}
```

When I receive an object of this type, I want to examine the state/value of its fields. The two approaches I do to analyze it are:

1. create getter methods in my Car class then use it (inside Log.d statement) everytime I want to check
2. use the debugger in Android Studio or in Eclipse

Is there any other ways to do it with efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this nifty solution in my online class. You can use the `toString` method of the object. In my case I added

```
public class Car {
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "mName='" + mName + '\'' +
                ", mBrand='" + mBrand + '\'' +
                ", mModel='" + mModel + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to check for your object's state, just do:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Current car: " + carInstance);
```

Cheers!

Comment: You could also use JSON libraries such as Gson to essentially build the same string